# Exporting Environment Variables in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables

I know many people have asked about environment variables before, but I am having a hard time dealing with these paths while ensuring I don't mess around with the original settings. How would you go about executing these commands in Ubuntu in terms of environment variables? Thanks in advance!

> Please put
>   /home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/bin:/home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/unix:/home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/tk8.4.18/unix
>   into your PATH environment; so that
>   you'll be able to run
>   itm/tclsh/wish/xgraph.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTICES:
>
> (1) You MUST put
>   /home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/otcl-1.13,
>   /home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/lib,
>       into your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
>       If it complains about X libraries, add path to your X libraries 
>       into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
>       If you are using csh, you can set it like:        setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   
>       If you are using sh, you can set it like:         export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
>
> (2) You MUST put
>   /home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/library
>   into your TCL_LIBRARY environmental
>       variable. Otherwise ns/nam will complain during startup.

Comment: If you simply use the export command the env variables will reset to normal when you reset your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using sh based shells, one of which seems to be default in ubuntu, type the following commands and you'll be fine:

```
export PATH=/home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/bin:/home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/unix:/home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/tk8.4.18/unix:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<Path to X libraries>

export TCL_LIBRARY=/home/stanley/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/library
```

None of these is persistent, and will be lost as soon as you close the terminal. So you'll have to enter them again. You can add them to your .bashrc/.bash_profile/.profile if you want them to be persistent.

Comment: I couldn't find .bashrc folder on my profile on Ubuntu. Where is it?

Comment: Its a file in your home folder. If you open terminal and type ls $HOME/.bashrc, you'll see it.
Or you could show hidden files in the nautilus and double click on .bashrc in your home folder.
All this is assuming that it already exists. If it doesn't, try with the other files I mentioned.